# How to get count of non-duplicate elements in a column list in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have dug through many of `SO` posts to just find a `Pandas` solution that match my case but I could not.

**The issue I have is** that I have `Dataframe` which looks something like below:

```
$ df
  email               hashes  
0 user@example.com    (iz3s65inn942j1bmedv., iz3s65inn942j1bmedv., 10$0mw1ewlhqlm0l)
```

In my case `nunique()` and `drop_duplicates()` does not work as I need to get count of non-duplicate elements in the tuple itself. In the above case the outcome would be:

```
$ df
  email               hashes
0 user@example.com    1
```

How can I achieve this outcome and get count of non-duplicate elements of the tuple in hashes column?

Comment: @jezrael `drop_duplicates` works on rows of dataframes not on a tuple inside of a column. Nothing happens on the row if you call that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with `Counter` for count unique values only:

```
from collections import Counter

df['hashes'] = df['hashes'].apply(lambda x: sum(v == 1 for k, v in Counter(x).items()))
print (df)
              email  hashes
0  user@example.com       1
```

Pandas only alternative with `DataFrame` cosntructor and [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df['hashes'] = pd.DataFrame(df['hashes'].tolist(), index=df.index).nunique(axis=1)
print (df)
              email  hashes
0  user@example.com       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the following function, to be applied to each group of rows:

```
def uniqCnt(grp):
    return grp.hashes.drop_duplicates(keep=False).size
```

Then apply it to the "explodad" version of *df*, grouped by *email*:

```
result = df.explode(column='hashes').groupby('email').apply(uniqCnt).rename('hashes')
```

The result is the following *Series*:

```
email
user@example.com    1
Name: hashes, dtype: int64
```

*email* is the name of the index column (left column) and values are in
the right column.